# .NET could not find any installed .NET Core SDKs after installing and restarting computer

Tags: windows-10, installation, 64-bit, .net-framework

Recently, I've been wanting to learn C# more or even migrate to its language as it has mostly the same syntax as Java, so I tried yesterday to do so.

The problem is, I downloaded the installer (Runtime and SDK), and even restarted my computer after installation, but whenever I try to run the command `dotnet new console`, it outputs this:

```
It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

What is the specific problem to this? is it the installer that is breaking this?

Here are problems that may or may not effect this:

- Is it because I'm on a Bootcamp drive?
- Do I need to install the 32bit installer even though I'm on a 64bit pc?
- What is Arm64 vs x64? (I installed the x64 version)
- Am I using an outdated visual studio code or terminal? (My VSC is version 1.55.2, checked in about)

Things I have done:

- Installed the SDK separately
- Copied/Pasted the binaries for the .NET 5.0 SDK
- I used `dotnet --info` and came out with NO SDK

Here is what outputs when I run the command `dotnet --info`:

```
Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.12
  Commit:  0267ad09c6

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  No SDKs were found.

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.12 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.12 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

If anyone knows the problem, it would be very helpful! Thanks alot!

~ Pale_Gray